# UITextField inside UIAlertView: how to select text?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I need to show an UIAlertView asking the user to change some text, but most times the user will want to: a) leave the text as it is or b) replace the whole text. In very rare occasions will he want to just change the text by appending or modifying it.

So, for this purpose I've come up with the following piece of code:

```
UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Name for your item"
                                                    message:nil
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                          otherButtonTitles:@"Accept", nil];
alertView.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
UITextField *textField = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];
textField.text = @"Some random text";
[alertView show];

UITextRange *textRange = [textField textRangeFromPosition:textField.beginningOfDocument
                                               toPosition:textField.endOfDocument];
[textField setSelectedTextRange:textRange];
```

This works fine on iPhone, the text is selected when the alert is shown and it works as I'd expect, but on the iPad the text is just not selected at all.

Am I doing something wrong, is this a bug on iOS or maybe this behavior is documented somewhere I haven't found?

Comment: I'd log the text range variable to see if it's 0 or NULL.

Comment: @Opsi Your code works for me in the iPad simulator under both iOS 5 and iOS 6.  What's your test environment?

Comment: That was quick ;) Indeed, it seems like the range is nil on the iPad but not on the iPhone so I guess it's my time to go fill a bug... thanks!

Comment: @Opsi It also works correctly for me on my iPad 3 running iOS 6.0.1.

Comment: @robmayoff I'm running it on 5.1, XCode 4.5.2, I will try on 6

Comment: @Opsi FYI, I put your code in the view controller's `viewDidAppear:` method.

Comment: for me the behavior is the same on 6.0... I will have to do more research on my devices, maybe is just the simulator, but at least now I know that is not a expected behavior... thanks!

PS: In my case the code is inside an IBAction on a UITableViewCell subclass, not sure if that's relevant

Answer (score 0):

```
UIAlertView *alertView=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"name" message:@"" delegate:self
                                            cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];

alertViewt.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
UITextField *textField = [Renamealert textFieldAtIndex:0];
textField.text=@"XYZZZ   ";
[alertView show];

UITextRange *textRange = [textField textRangeFromPosition:textField.beginningOfDocument
                                               toPosition:textField.endOfDocument];
[textField setSelectedTextRange:textRange];
```

Comment: I don't see what this answer adds to the original question... could you elaborate a bit?